# Python regex to get values from keys:

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I would like to get specific data values based on a match for a specific ID which is not sorted and could be anywhere in the line. Here is an example:

```
[ROUTE:10:23:191:271:3:81]
     route_protocol = ripv2
     dhcp_enabled = yes
     route_config = dynamic
```

How can I get the route_protocol value only for ROUTE IDs: 23 and 81?

Comment: You could use a `str` method, `.split(':')`, and grab the values at the indices you want.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Is this an INI file?

Comment: Please show a more complete example and expected output.

Comment: Hi Jon, the file is a text file with a config on that format. So I need to create a regular expression that:
1) find the [ROUTE\:
2) then the ID (for example: 23)
3) then if that is found, I want to get the route_protocol = data

     [ROUTE:{ID}]
            value = data

Comment: @squid22 is it actually a proper INI file though?

Comment: @JonClements, no is not

Comment: Might want to make that clear as it looks like it could be. Is it any other common format etc...?

Comment: @JonClements this is not an INI file. This is a text file that you can generate from a device after you configure it. The file is completely on that format. All the networks have an ID and then the ID is used to provide related configuration values of the network based on the ID. So if i can find the ID, I should be able to easily get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the values in a list in order of appearance.

```
with open('conftxt.txt') as config:
    l = [x for x in config.readlines() if 'route_config' in x]
    route_config_vals = [x.strip().split(' = ')[1] for x in l]

print(route_config_vals) #['dynamic']
```

EDIT

```
def extract_values(param: "str paramaeter to search for",
                   ) -> "dict:  ROUTE: param pairs":


  with open('conftxt.txt') as config:
        parameter_list = []

        # get list of parameters
        l = [x for x in config.readlines() if param in x]
        parameter_list= [x.strip().split(' = ')[1] for x in l]

        config.seek(0)  #back to top of file

        # get list of routes
        route_list = [x.strip() for x in config.readlines() if 'ROUTE' in x]
        pairs = {k: v for k, v in zip(route_list, parameter_list)}
        return pairs


print(extract_values('route_config'))  #{'[ROUTE:10:23:191:271:3:81]': dynamic'}
print(extract_values('dhcp_enabled'))  #{'[ROUTE:10:23:191:271:3:81]': 'yes'}
```

Comment: I will try this :) Thank you!

Comment: No prob. Are you wanting the route in squared brackets to be mapped to it's route_config value?

Comment: The thing with the file is that there can be other route_configs:

`[ROUTE:10:23:191:271:3:81]`
    `route_protocol = ripv2`
     `dhcp_enabled = yes`
     `route_config = dynamic`

`[ROUTE:99:123]`
    ` route_protocol = ospf`
     `dhcp_enabled = no`
     `route_config = dynamic`

Comment: My goal is to be able to say:

`print "Network {} is configured as: {}".format(id, route_config)`

Comment: Check my edit, Its' designed so you can specify a parameter to search for an it will iterate through the file and make a dictionary of route: parameter_value pairs. You can then just iterate through the dictionary and do what you need with it.